# Use angular service from jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

For reasons, I prefer to write my app with JQuery direct dom manipulation. However, I think the angular $http service is much better than the $ajax method. How can I call $http from a non-angular web app?

I suppose that I could create a dummy app/controller whose only purpose is to copy a reference to $http into global scope.

```
<div ng-app="xx" ng-controller="yy"/>
<script>
    var myhttp = null;
    angular.module('xx',[]).controller('yy', function($http) { myhttp = $http; });
</script>
```

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Hi John, you are currently loading the whole of angular just for $http. I suggest you either choose to go fully with either angular or jquery. Mixing both is not that good, the http service is built especially for angular and is not made to be used elsewhere, It's liked with the $digest cycles and many other parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an adapter for jQuery's $.ajax that implements Angular's $http interface.

Your current approach is not optimal. As you are aware `$http` is tightly coupled to Angular's DI implementation.

I am curious what is it about the AngularJS `$http` service that you prefer over jQuery's Ajax methods? Both return promises.

Comment: in $http the promises have consistent parameters (response) whereas in $ajax they are confusing, sometimes jqxhr. sometimes first, sometimes third. sometimes activex. Furthermore, i have tested code that depends on $http. I don't want to rewrite it to use $ajax.  But I like your suggestion. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Following Martin's advice here is the code I wrote. It's not fully tested,

```
// This is a wrapper to cause the $.ajax api to act like the $http api (mostly)
function fake$http() {
    'use strict';
    var $http = function (settings) {
        return $.ajax(settings)
        .then(function (data, status, jqxhr) {
            return {
                data: data,
                status: jqxhr.status,
                config: settings,
                statusText: jqxhr.statusText
            };
        }, function (jqxhr) {
            return {
                data: jqxhr.responseText,
                status: jqxhr.status,
                config: settings,
                statusText: jqxhr.statusText
            };
        });
    };

    $http.get = function (url, config) {
        return $http($.extend({ url: url, method: 'GET' }, config));
    };
    $http.post = function (url, data, config) {
        return $http($.extend({ url: url, method: 'POST', data: data }, config));
    };
    $http.put = function (url, data, config) {
        return $http($.extend({ url: url, method: 'PUT', data: data }, config));
    };
    $http.delete = function (url, config) {
        return $http($.extend({ url: url, method: 'DELETE' }, config));
    };
    return $http;
}
```

The response.header is missing. Many other differences such as cors, jsonp, etc, etc.